# Firebase - Unable to read data on application interface - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a task management application on Android Studio with Firebase. I have created a class to add data to the database but I have tried multiple approaches to integrate and read the data on the application with no progress.

Main Activity.java

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = database.getReference().child("Task List");
    final ArrayList<String> mTaskName = new ArrayList<>();

    taskListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.taskListView);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.task_info, mTaskName);
    taskListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mTaskName.add(value);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

add_task.java

```
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Task List"); // Reference database

    addTaskbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String taskName = newTask.getText().toString().trim();
            String date = dateField.getText().toString().trim();
            String assignee = spinnerAssign.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String descrip = description.getText().toString();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(taskName) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(date)) {

                HashMap<String, String> taskData = new HashMap<>();
                taskData.put("Name", taskName);
                taskData.put("Date", date);
                taskData.put("Assigned to", assignee);
                taskData.put("Description", descrip);

                mDatabase.push().setValue(taskData).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
```

The database is structured like this:

task-list-for-managers 
 
  -Task List 
 
       -PushID 
        -Assigned to: "Name"
        -Date: "Date" 
        -Description: "Description" 
        -Name: "Task Name"

Comment: is the 'OnCompleteListener' callback called with a successful result?
To actually display the data try to implement 'addSingleValueEventListener' instead of 'ChildEventListener'.

Comment: Hi Marco, is this what you mean?    'ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            Override
            public void onDataChange(NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    task = ds.getValue(Task.class);
                    list.add(task.getName());

                }//for
                taskListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            Override
            public void onCancelled(NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });'

Comment: if you only need to show the list use the 'addListenerForSingleValueEvent' that is fired only once (to retrieve the list), as explained here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-reading-once.
Don't forget to call 'notifyDataSetChanged()' to updated the local list.

Comment: I've implemented that but nothing seems to have really changed. I don't receive any data on the list view. Also if I try to get to my add_task page my app crashes.

Comment: Also just to make things clearer, I want to be able to view the data with or without adding new data via the app.

Comment: Is the data correctly stored on Firebase? Also, I strongly suggest you to use the 'FirebaseUI' component (https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md): basically you can attach a query straight to a RecyclerView. If you want to do it manually make sure that both callbacks ('OnCompleteListener' to write data and 'onChildAdded' to read data) are called with success.

Comment: I'm not particularly used to recyclerView yet, I did another approach with recyclerView before but I had no luck with that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        //Searching the database and adding each to list
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //adding the key to an arraylist to be referenced when deleting records or passing intents from specific button
                mTaskName.add(ds.getKey());
                String name = ds.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                String date = ds.child("Date").getValue(String.class);
                id.add(name  + "\n" + date);
                Log.d("TAG", name);
            }
            taskListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```